# How can I count image downloads using Apache 2.2 on windows-7?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, image, count

What is an easy way to count downloads of an image file so that I can count how many times my Craigslist ad is read to see how often that converts to a hit on my site?  This is for windows-7 running Apache v2.2.

Ideal would be to create a webpage on my server that is for internal consumption that lists the number of page hits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run something like [awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) against your logs. Or just do a simple grep (find) on the log and count the entries for that file name.

Comment: This is not Unix, so I don't think grep is an option on windows.

Comment: http://www.wingrep.com/ - or `FindStr` (http://scripthacks.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/grep-equivalent-for-windows-string-parsing/)

Comment: and there is a grep port in unixutils(http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I believe that for large files these figures can be notably skewed (partial downloads, incomplete downloads, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

[awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/) is a good log file analyser. Otherwise you can grep the logs by hand.